# Some harmonic analysis notation questions

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

I'm reading a paper which contains the following line:

$$\|\pi(\mu)f\|^{2n}= \bigg(\int_G\langle \pi(g)f,f\rangle d(\mu^\ast\ast\mu)\bigg)^n$$

Here $G$ is a Lie group, $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $G$, $\pi$ is a unitary representation of $G$ on $X$, and $f$ is an $L^2$ function on $X$ with zero mean.  This is part of a longer chain of equivalences, so I'm not even sure if this is supposed to be a definition or not.  **So my questions are: what does $\pi(\mu)f$ mean? what is the norm $\|\cdot\|$? and what is $\mu^\ast$?**

The paper is *Spectral transfer and pointwise ergodic theorems for semi-simple Kazhdan groups* available [here](http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/1998/0005/0003/MRL-1998-0005-0003-a005.pdf)

The line appears near the bottom of the second page.